# How to check country short form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having these two table's

```
Country Table                           Details Table

Id CountryId CountryName                Id CountryId   Description
--------------------------              ---------------------------
1      1     UK                         1      1       xxxxx  
2      2     USA                        2      2       YYYYY
```

Design Page
[image]

i will collect country name and description and save details to database
**My Problem**
if user give the country name as `United Kingdom` and give description and click save..
@the time i my database i will use it as `UK` But user enter as `United Kingdom` **occurs mismatch**  
if User enter as full formed country_name how to i identify the short form of that particular country.

**For example:**`if user enter United Kingdom convert to UK` 
How do i will check it..
**`is there any online website to do this?`**

Please Say any Idea.
~Thanks.

Comment: You should use a combobox or listview for this, you give the user too many options this way.

Comment: @Max Mommersteeg by textbox i want to do this..do u have any idea..

Comment: If the user types 'UK' do they mean United Kingdom or Ukraine or something else?

Comment: is there any online website to check these?

Comment: there  is no other idea than Max's comment

Comment: If you use a textbox you should validate the country on client side. Thus you will avoid misunderstandings like the one Jodrell exposed

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Comment: Is there any website's to Make these conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Max is right! @GOPI if you want this way, use a Dictionary class to map user input. Use Hashtable in Dictionary class for auto suggestion and easy implementation. And also notify user about wrong inpur(in case if user inputs United Kingkong insted of United Kingdom).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it via a textbox but still make sure the country code is selected I suggest you use one of jQuery's AutoComplete features.
I suggest you have a look at [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Check out section Basics. It does exactly what you need it for (it even has example for country codes).[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Max suggest it, you should use a ComboBox to force the user to choose a "good" option.

However, if you really need a text box, you should use anopther column in your `Country` table called `CountryShortForm` for example. Strore in this colum the short form of the country, like `UK` for `United Kingdom`.
Then, when you save your data, just take a look if what is entered correspond to the `CountryName` or the `CountryShortForm`.


**But attention**, nothing prevent the users to enter `ENG` or `U-K` for exemple, so be really careful with TextBoxes... which are definitively not the good choice here !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select ct.CountryName from Country.Table ct 
inner join Country.Details cd on ct.CountryId = cd.CountryId
where cd.Description = 'United Kingdom'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

```
// Get first two characters
string sub = input.Substring(0, 2);
```